# PyQt5) I'm Try to open QFileDialog on the main window but QFileDialog skips the main window

Tags: pyqt5, qfiledialog

I'm trying to open QFileDialog widget when I click the push button on the main window.
but after I run the code QfileDialog widget is opened without main window widget.

Below is my code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys

class Python_Install(QtWidgets.QWidget) :
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('main_window')
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        # add GroupBox
        self.gb = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self)
        self.gb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 120, 731, 331))
        self.gb.setTitle('Select File')
        # LB_host + LE1(LineEdit) + FC1(File Choose)
        self.LB_host = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.gb)
        self.LB_host.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 70, 121, 18))
        self.LB_host.setText('host file :')
        self.LE1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.gb)
        self.LE1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 60, 301, 25))
        self.LE1.setReadOnly(True)
        self.FC1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.gb)
        self.FC1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 60, 112, 34))
        self.FC1.clicked.connect(self.File_Choose(self.LE1))

    def File_Choose(self, X):
        file, check = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Select File', "", "All Files (*);;Text Files (*.txt)")
        if check:
            X.setText(file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = Python_Install()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I think this part of the code is wrong...

```
        self.FC1.clicked.connect(self.File_Choose(self.LE1))

    def File_Choose(self, X):
        file, check = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Select File', "", "All Files (*);;Text Files (*.txt)")
        if check:
            X.setText(file)
```

Because If I change that part as below, It works as I indented :

```
    self.FC1.clicked.connect(self.File_Choose)

def File_Choose(self):
    file, check = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Select File', "", "All Files (*);;Text Files (*.txt)")
    if check:
        self.LE1.setText(file)
```

But... what I want is passing the QLineEdit object to 'File_Choose' slot when 'push button' clicked event occurs and writing the chosen file name to the QLineEdit object.

how could I fix it...?

Comment: `self.FC1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.File_Choose(self.LE1))`

Comment: ...! It perfectly works...! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Please don't put "solved" in the question title, this is not a forum.

Comment: ok! I'll keep it in mind. If I do some mistakes, please tell me. it may takes time to get used to the rules. Thank you :D